# Larger Touch Screen Displays

Tags: hdmi, display, touchscreen

I was hoping to find a larger touchscreen display that will work with my Raspberry Pi. I wanted to make a "kitchen use" kiosk for looking up recipes, watching cooking shows etc. I was hoping to find a touch screen display that was 14" or larger maybe up to 23.1" full 1080p (1920x1080 resolution). Multi-touch would be nice but I suppose its not as needed as the resolution and size.

My goal is to make this thing something that can swing down from a cabinet, easily interacted with, looks great, and can be wiped off cause it'll get messy.

there was a 14" display used in the "little box" project here

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1008225922/littlebox-the-diy-raspberry-pi-all-in-one-desktop

I've looked around and I find talk of such displays but I can't actually find them. Does anyone know of such a display? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I just want to add something I found for anyone else that comes across this.


http://www.chalk-elec.com/?page_id=1280#!/15-6-HDMI-interface-LCD-with-capacitive-touchscreen/p/38127425/category=3094861

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options. In increasing order of difficulty.

1. You can buy USB touch screen from somewhere like elo touch, but be prepared to spend
   ~$400 for a resistive 15" screen.
2. You could buy a touch overlay kit from ebay and apply it to an ordinary hdmi monitor.
3. Finally, you could buy and lvds to hdmi convertor from somewhere like 
   http://www.njytouch.com/ctp.htm and try and try to get a generic touch panel from 
   china working with your raspberry pi.

Comment: If I am going to be able to use the Pi for this project the touch overlay is going to be the way to go. Now I have to decide if I want to use the Pi or an android PC as if I go the Pi route there will be a TON of custom code/software I'll have to do.

Answer (score 5):

HP's L2105tm is a 21.5 inch 1080x1920 touch monitor that works flawlessly with the Raspberry Pi. It isn't resistive, so the response is slower than what you will be used to if you have used a resistive touch screen. But if you have not used a resistive touch screen, you'd never call it "slow".

I bought a hand full of this model a few years ago for right at $300 each. I see now that many places are selling a 2206tm for under $300, and my bet is that it will also work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.chalk-elec.com/?page_id=1280#!/%7E/product/category=3094861&id=14647624) is the largest touch screen that I could find for the Raspberry Pi (10"):

[image]

Info from the website:

> This plug-and-play bundle includes:
>
> - 10" glossy screen LCD with IPS technology, 1280x800 px, 256K    (18-bits) colors with integrated multi-points capacitive touchscreen with USB interface (USB cable for touchscreen is included)
> - new HDMI-LVDS converter board that has all required voltages for LCD, can power RaspberryPi through USB connector, contains PIC controller that can be programmed to provide EDID information (like screen resolution, etc) over DDC/I2C interface and also can control LCD brightness in automatic (with help of ambient light sensor) or manual mode
> - LVDS cable
> - ambient light sensor (can be connected as a part of LVDS cable to HDMI-LVDS converter) for automatic LCD brightness control
>
> Can be connected to virtually any HDMI source that can provide native
> LCD
> resolution.
>
> Additionally you can order power adapter to power whole system
> (RaspberryPi + HDMI-LVDS
> converter + LCD) and short
> USB-microUSB cable (7.5cm/3") to power RasPi right from HDMI
> converter.

[Here is a video of it in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llC-gVw1wBs).

Comment: Yeah that is the largest I have found and I am afraid dirty cumbersome fingers will make it hard to use at that size. I'm wondering what screen was use in that kickstarter project because that might be perfect.  If I don't get any hits in the next few days I'll accept this answer to give credit where its due. cheers

Answer (score 1):

check out the Gechic line of touchscreens

http://www.gechic.com/product_en.asp

the 1502i is a multi touch HDMI thin monitor

Answer (score 1):

Currently we use at work 19" Zytronic's Zybrid (3mm glass with capacitive layer) touch screens with 1440x900 monitors with USB driver board /panel+driver is ~200$/. During this year will switch to 21,5" and 1920x1080.

With default setup it works with built-in hid multitouch kernel driver. As we needed some advanced functions of USB driver board, we signed some documents with Zytronic and got source code for drivers to compile kernel driver modules for our custom kernel.

We use common consumer monitors, dissasemble them to get LCD panel and interface electronic. This we assembly into our device using orignal interface electronics from monitor, connect with cheap hdmi-dvi cable. The device is then mounted behind two layered vandal-proof glass.

Panel with driver board itself supports multiple touch events. We did some experiments with MT interface but haven't let it in production yet.

Answer (score 0):

For the talented do-it-yourselfer, the [Waveshare 15.6" Capacitive Touch Screen LCD, 1920×1080, HDMI, IPS](https://www.waveshare.com/15.6inch-hdmi-lcd.htm) multi-touch might be a good choice, especially at only $160 currently.  Ideal to build into something else; I've been slowly building a [LinuxCNC](http://linuxcnc.org) touch-pedestal around it`*`.  Apparently it'll work with other devices as well (untested.)

[image: Waveshare 15.6" Touchscreen]

Notes:

- Read the website details carefully; there may be some changes needed in the RPi's `config.txt` to recognize this display at full resolution/at all.
- It is *very* thin, sans the PCB on the back.  This might be great if you need a low profile.  If you can countersink the entire outline into your enclosure just 0.092"/2.3mm, it can be flush with the top surface.  The edge of the glass  is not rounded, so this would look really nice.
- The bezel came with adhesive film already applied to the rear.  There are *no* mounting screws.  The website gives a suggested mounting drawing, with some custom fab work necessary.  Might be "easy enough" with a big 3D printer and some threaded inserts.
- It is shipped from China, so expect that delivery speed.

`*` = LinuxCNC on the RPi is a giant can of worms... suggest Linux & Pi experts only attempt going down that road.