# touch screen for the pi

Tags: usb, touchscreen

I am trying to set up a touch screen for the pi.  I am looking for a 20 in. or so touch screen.  I will be mounting this in the kitchen and the 10 in. one is a little to small.  Can I use any USB powered touch screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Larger Touch Screen Displays](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/larger-touch-screen-displays)