# What to look for in a large HDMI+USB touchscreen for raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, usb, hdmi, touchscreen

I have been searching quite a bit for a larger (14"+) monitor that has basic out of the box touchscreen capability with the raspberry pi. One that uses USB for the touch connection and preferably HDMI for the video. Some of the posts I found:

[Larger Touch Screen Displays](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/larger-touch-screen-displays)

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=8983&start=75
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=116174&p=911993

But the posts are old enough that those monitors are hard/impossible to get.
Specifically I am looking for one that works (at a basic level) without having to recompile the kernel for touchscreen support. All I would need is "left-click" style detection of when a user touches the screen.

I know that the HDMI side is standardized enough not to worry about, but how can I find out whether an appropriate display's USB touchscreen is going to work out-of-the-box on Raspbian?

Comment: Since "purchasing recommendations" are [explicitly off-topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I've tweaked this a bit to keep it a little more in-bounds.

Comment: Success reported with the [Hannspree H231](https://www.hannspree.eu/en/monitors/ht-series/ht231hpb) [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=129184), with no wacky driver shenanigans. It's going to be relatively difficult, I think, to come up with a definitive list of working touchscreens - screen manufacturers don't normally publish their component chipsets.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be very difficult to find that in the US. Sellers that have it don't ship to the US, and random users selling it on ebay are charging 100 euro+ for shipping alone.

Comment: I am going to try a dell S2240T monitor since people have said that it works. I will answer here if this works out, since this can be found easily online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the monitor I tested (dell S2240T) worked perfectly. I am using SDL1.2 and its event structures to capture mouse left click press/release. I do not think multitouch works, but it is not needed for me.

Answer (score 3):

The Dell s2240Tb is working out of the box with Raspian Buster on a Raspberry Pi 4, including two-finger zoom...